# Find the Friday of previous/last week in python

Tags: python, datetime

Eg1. Suppose I have a day 4/30/07 .Then I need to get 4/27/07.

Eg2. Suppose I have a day 6/29/07 .Then I need to get 6/22/07.

Comment: not necessarily. actually i just wrote very similar code (get the monday of the week indicated by a random date withing that week) less than a day ago for a timetable for one of my websites.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Assuming `day` is a `datetime.date` or `datetime.datetime` object, this code creates a `datetime`/`date` object for last week's friday:

```
friday = day - timedelta(days=day.weekday()) + timedelta(days=4, weeks=-1)
```

Explanation: `timedelta(days=day.weekday())` is the offset between monday and `day` so adding 4 days and subtracting one week will get you last week's friday.

Of course you can simplify this (`+4d -1w = -3d`):

```
friday = day - timedelta(days=day.weekday() + 3)
```

Note: To get `timedelta`, use `from datetime import timedelta` or just `import datetime` and use `datetime.timedelta`

Comment: That doesn't work on Saturday and Sunday. Try this: `friday = day - timedelta(days=(day.weekday() - 4) % 7, weeks=-1)`

Comment: With which date did you have this problem? I tested with 2012-09-08 and 2012-09-09 and my code correctly gave me 2012-08-31 while yours resulted in 2012-09-14

Comment: My code should be `weeks=0` (or omit the argument). I miss-posted. Also, the desired result depends on what you mean by "previous/last week" and whether you define a week starting on Sunday or Monday. I may have misinterpreted the question. My (corrected) code gives the most recent Friday.

Comment: Ah well, for me a week starts on monday... Feel free to post another answer mentioning that yours assumes weeks start on sunday.

Answer (score 34):

An another and easier way is to use [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil).
To get the previous Friday :

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, FR
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime(2015, 7, 8) + relativedelta(weekday=FR(-1))
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 3, 0, 0)
```

And the next Friday :

```
>>> datetime(2015, 7, 8) + relativedelta(weekday=FR(+1))
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 10, 0, 0)
```

Comment: This should be the top answer, no?

Answer (score 4):

Not specific to Friday, but given a day "taget_dayofweek" (where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6)

```
from datetime import datetime

target_dayofweek = 4  # Friday
current_dayofweek = datetime.now().weekday() # Today


if target_dayofweek <= current_dayofweek:
    # target is in the current week
    endDate = datetime.now() - timedelta(current_dayofweek - target_dayofweek)

else: 
    # target is in the previous week
    endDate = datetime.now() - timedelta(weeks=1) + timedelta(target_dayofweek - current_dayofweek)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of options in [pandas.tseries.offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/offset_frequency.html#week)
This one is for previous week friday.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Week
f_dates = required_df.index - Week(1, weekday=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_object = datetime.date.today()
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
previousWeekLastDay = date_object + relativedelta(weekday=SU(-1))
previousWeekFirstDay = previousWeekLastDay + relativedelta(weekday=MO(-1))
print(previousWeekFirstDay)
print(previousWeekLastDay)

previoustopreviousWeekLastDay1= date_object + relativedelta(weekday=SU(-2))
previoustopreviousWeekFirstDay1= previousWeekLastDay1 + relativedelta(weekday=MO(-1))
print(previoustopreviousWeekFirstDay1)
print(previoustopreviousWeekLastDay1)
```